# In Bitbucket, why is this folder weird? Its data does not get cloned

Tags: git, bitbucket

this vpn/ folder is part of my project. I have just realized that it doesn't get saved on Bitbucket. And when I clone the project it just does not download. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What's going on with this folder?
I've had something similar happen in the past, using submodules. But in this case I'm pretty sure I didn't use these, and there is no .git/ folder in vpn/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a folder. It's a submodule.

Comment: Ah, I remember now. This vpn/ folder used to be its own git repo, but not anymore. There is no .git/ folder in vpn/, and there is no .gitmodules file anywhere in the project.
What else could make it be considered a submodule?

Comment: @mascip So it _was_ a submodule?

Comment: Yes it was. I guessed that without a .git/ subfolder, it wouldn't be considered a submodule anymore. Why was I wrong?

Comment: I mean: why am I wrong, thinking that a folder without a .git/ subfolder shouldn't be considered a submodule? What else makes it stand out as a submodule? I don't have a .gitmodules file either.

I don't understand why Bitbucket still thinks it's a submodule.

Comment: Oh. I fixed it. I copied the folder somewhere else. "git rm" it from the Git repo. Re-copied it in the repo. That did the trick. Thank you for your help :-)